# Storing output of commands and splitting the resulting string in Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a simple task I'd like to do where I fetch the domain information from a host (using the output from ipconfig /all) and using that string later on in the script. Essentially, what I'd like to do is:

1.) Store the output of `ipconfig /all | find "DNS Suffix Search List"` In a variable (let's call it str), and subsequently split it by the colon so that I just obtain the domain, via:

```
set "domain=%str:*: =%"
```

Is this doable in Batch? Everything I've looked at seems to be overcomplicating it by using for loops and/or storing the output of various commands in temporary text files.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %A in ('ipconfig /all ^| Findstr /i /c:"DNS Suffix Search List"') Do @Echo %A`

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly for printing out what I'm looking for to STDOUT, but how do I store it as a variable in the batch script?

Comment: `set a=%A`. Remember %%A in a batch file. See `For /?`, `set /?`, `findstr /?`, `ipconfig /?`. Also type `help`.